# React Router v4 components with similar paths (fixed and dynamic path param) are "overlapping"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My routes are set up like this:

```
<Route path="/chat/:id" component={Chat} />
<Route path="/chat/new" component={NewChat} />
```

When I go to `chat/new` its also displaying `{Chat}`. Is there any way to exclusively call `NewChat` when I go to `/chat/new`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would make use of `Switch` and reorder your Routes, since [`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) renders the first matched `Route`

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/chat/new" component={NewChat} />
   <Route path="/chat/:id" component={Chat} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route 
    path="/chat/:id/" 
    render={ props => { 

        if( props.location.pathname != '/chat/new') return <Chat {...props} /> 
        else return null;

    } } 
/>
<Route path="/chat/new" component={NewChat} />
```

Depends on your set up this could be the solution as well